# Find minor matrix in python

Tags: python, matrix

```
def getMatrixMinor(m,i,j):
    return [row[:j] + row[j+1:] for row in (m[:i]+m[i+1:])]
```

The above is the code that I find on the stack overflow in order to find the inverse of a matrix, however, I am really new in python. Can anybody explain the behind mechanism in order to construct a matrix of minor by using this code?

By the way, I've used this code and it works but I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: How much do you already know about Python’s slices?

Comment: I know that row[:j] is getting all element from index 0 to before j(excluded j) and row[j+1:] is getting all the element form j+1 to the rest. Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the definition of `(i,j)th` minor matrix of a matrix:

> `(i,j)th` minor of a matrix of size `n` is a smaller matrix of size `n-1` with the `i'th` row and `j'th` column deleted.

Now lets look at this python one liner:

```
[row for row in (m[:i] + m[i+1:])]
```

`m[:i]` gives the first `i` rows of `m` (remember that we are representing a matrix as a list of rows, and adding two lists gives back a bigger list in python), now let's look at another one liner:

```
row[:j] + row[j+1:]
```

This gives us all the elements of a row except the `j'th` element (lst[a:b] gives a list with elements from `lst` between `a` and `b`, with `b` excluded)

Combine the above two and you get an expression which returns `a new matrix with i'th row and j'th column excluded`:

```
def getMatrixMinor(m,i,j):
    return [row[:j] + row[j+1:] for row in (m[:i]+m[i+1:])]
```

Which is the minor matrix.

Comment: Wow!! this makes much more sense. Thank you so much, sir.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I just started to use StackOverflow for real by sign up to the site just two days ago.

Answer (score 0):

The function is very simple, used to compute the first minor matrices. Suppose you have a squared matrix of size `m x m`, and you want to compute the first minor matrix at position `(i,j)`, what do you do? You have to extract a smaller matrix of size `(m-1) x (m-1)` from the original matrix by removing the row `i`*-th* and the column `j`-*th*, which is done by the function.

Concretely, `m[:i]+m[i+1:]` removes the `i`-*th* row and creates a new list of the remaining rows. For each row in this list, the function remove the element `row[j]`. The output of the function is a list of lists (rows) representing the corresponding minor matrix.

I recommend you to have a look at Python [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) and [list slicing](https://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/).

Comment: Thank you so much sir, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be useful for somebody, just want to share with you my working solution, any constructive critic is acceptable

```
def getMatrixMinor(arr,i,j):
    c = arr[:]
    c = np.delete(c, (i),axis=0)
    return [np.delete(row, (j),axis=0) for row in (c)]
```

As practical example you can see my implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819500/code-to-solve-determinant-using-python-without-using-scipy-linalg-det/65429536#65429536)  based on this function for determinant calculation.

Answer (score -1):

```
# Finding minors of a matrix and it's determinant

import numpy as np
from numpy import *

n = 4
arr = random.randint(0,10,(n,n))
print(arr)

def getMatrixMinor(arr,i,j):
    c = arr[:]
    c_r = np.delete(c, (i),axis=0) # deletes i-th row
    c_c = np.delete(c_r, (j),axis=1) #deletes j-th column
    return c_c

gmm = getMatrixMinor(arr,2,2)
print("gmm = \n",gmm)

d = linalg.det(gmm)
print("d =",d)

    [[6 3 4 6]
     [0 8 5 2]
     [2 9 6 3]
     [6 5 2 1]]
    gmm = 
     [[6 3 6]
     [0 8 2]
     [6 5 1]]
     d = -263.99999999999994,
     
     Thanks GoAI, mine is a slight change from your answer.
```

Comment: Please add some text outside of the code block which actually answers the question *"...Can anybody explain..."*.