# Minor of a Matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have run the below code in Python to generate minor of a matrix but am not getting the desired output.

```
import numpy as np 

m=np.array([(0,3,-1),(-1,11,-1),(2,-1,10)]) 

def getMatrixMinor(m,i,j): 

    return [row[:j] + row[j+1:] for row in (m[:i]+m[i+1:])]

getMatrixMinor(m,0,0)
```

If someone could pls suggest the corrections.

Comment: Is [Numpy Routine for Computing Matrix Minors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858213/numpy-routine-for-computing-matrix-minors) helpful?

Comment: look this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934405/find-minor-matrix-in-python

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I have ran the same code but not getting the desired outcome.

Comment: @ussu Could you please add the outcome you are getting and the desired output?

Comment: @YashShah Link suggested by Avik works fine.

Comment: When you add m[:i] to m[i+1:] what really happens is an addition of rows with broadcasting. If I understand correctly you wished to concatenate rows somehow. The ij-th minor will just delete the i-th row and j-th column so addition is probably not what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you:

```
def get_minor(numbers, i, j):
    minor = []

    for row in range(len(numbers[0])):

        col = 0
        min_row = []

        while (col < len(numbers[0])):

            row != i and col != j and min_row.append(numbers[row][col]) 
            col += 1
        
        len(min_row) and minor.append(min_row)

    return minor
```

Comment: It doesn't work yet. I guess you need to replace `numbers` with `m` in your definition.

Answer (score 0):

In case `m` is numpy array it can be done with this one-liner using [`np.ix_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) and boolean indexing:

```
import numpy as np
i, j = 0, 2
m[np.ix_(np.arange(len(m))!=i, np.arange(len(m[0]))!=j)]
```

Note that:

- looping `numpy` arrays is not efficient.
- my code can be optimized further:

  ```
   def get_minor(m,i,j):
       X = np.ones(len(m)).astype(bool)
       Y = np.ones(len(m[0])).astype(bool)
       X[i], Y[j] = False, False
       return m[np.ix_(X, Y)]
  ```